# How do I turn off the controller vibration?

Tags: controllers, windows-10

I'm using a wired xbox360 controller with Windows 10. I'd like to kill the controller vibration permanently, if I can - it messes with my motor control something awful.

I can't seem to find a setting to turn it off, though. Short of editing every game's config file or finding the in-game setting, is there a way to just say "Please don't rumble ever again, controller"?

Comment: Everything appears to be about turning it *on* because it doesn't work, nothing about turning it *off*...

Comment: @ben that was what I found too :(

Comment: Ok, I did find [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/how-to-turn-off-xbox-360-cortroller-vibration/fdb7df62-c516-4c82-8d89-90ebfab79c22) which may help...

Comment: @ben nope. In win 10 that just brings up the game bar and the Xbox app, neither have the option to turn off vibration

Comment: The only other option I can find is to just to disable it in the controller itself (like pull it apart and disconnect the weights/vibration motor/whatever it is)

Comment: AH! Yes, that's the one I was trying to remember... the [xbox360ce](http://www.x360ce.com/) will probably be your best bet. Using a bit of a work-around, you can disable the option [using the ini file](https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2183923#8).

Comment: I will not give the bounty to answers that just says "You can't, try X" unless you actually tell how to do X.

Comment: @ardaozkal is that in reference to my comments? I didn't want to add them as answers because I didn't feel that was the OP was looking for

Comment: @Ben No, it was a reference to my overall experience with StackExchange and for example Keagan's answer.

Answer (score 5):

I did some googling for you, and you can't turn it off, so I did more googling and found this video that someone made that shows how to remove motors.

You'll need a Torques T8 w/ security bit screwdriver.

1. Flip the controller over and remove battery pack and place it to the side. Remove 6 outer screws, and then remove the 7th screw last.
2. Grab charging port and mic connector, then pull the battery pack forward.
3. Ground yourself by touching metal. Remove white plugs, remove rumble motors and set to side.
4. Take back plate and put it back on with the controller buttons first. Push springs of battery in and make sure of its quick sound.
5. Screw the middle screw in first, then test if all buttons work. Screw in outer screws. Put battery pack in.

Credit to MrGradyIsCool from YouTube.

Comment: Please explain the steps in the video, possibly by using screenshots of the video (and crediting properly) as the video can go down, it might not be accessible.

Comment: Got it done, is it alright?

Comment: Yep, it is great. I'll probably award the bounty to you.

Comment: Thanks! But the bounty is quite much...

Comment: @YoshiLikes that's what the bounty is for - to award good answers!

Comment: @YoshiLikes your answer is good and you deserve the bounty... enjoy it.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks to you I can do much more here! I really appreciate`it.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of research and fooling around it seems like there is no known way to disable controller vibration and Microsoft has no tools to do so. You could always remove the vibrators in your controller physically as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want too, you can try to replace the DLL file (first make a backup of the original file).

You can take a look at this old [thread](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2230961&_ga=1.120893576.1652197745.1467666994). But anyway, beware! Even those DLLs can be compromised or may be outdated.
The thread points to this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/john-peterson/bin-patch/wiki/XInput), which provides the necessary DLLs.

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of that conversation to your answer as the link might go down in the future, making your answer invalid

Comment: Well, in those thread is just a reference to the GitHub Repo. And I can't put those DLL parts in here. This won't make much sense. ;-)